# AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'swapaxes'

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, torch

For some reason when using PyTorch on Google Colab, I'm unable to use [torch.swapaxes](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.swapaxes.html) and returns this error. Am I missing some additional import or something?

Comment: It is because colab uses Pytorch version 1.7.0 which doesn't have swap axes. `torch.transpose()` should do basically the same thing.

Comment: `torch.swapaxes` is actually an alias for `torch.transpose` as of PyTorch *1.8.0* (current **master** branch)